# Scala alpaakka s3 connect with DO Spaces multipart upload result 403

Tags: scala, digital-ocean, akka-http, alpakka

i am trying to setup akka-http file upload to Digital Ocean Spaces. And i have got problem with multipart upload. I use alpaakka to stream file directly to s3. However i get 403 error SignatureDoesNotMatch on upload. 
But if i try to upload same file with simple one part upload everything works fine.

```
s3Client.putObject(collection, key, file, 1, s3Headers = S3Headers(Seq())) //works fine 

file.runWith(s3Client.multipartUpload(collection, key)) // gets 403 and throws No Etag exists in response
```

Multipart upload initiate request succesfully and signature is valid, but when it tries to do actual upload of part then i get 403.

Anyone tried it with DO? I changed different settings, how i setup client (with Proxy, with Endpoint), but still same result.

```
//with Proxy
val proxy = Option(Proxy(url, port, "https"))
val settings = new S3Settings(MemoryBufferType, proxy, awsCredentialsProvider, regionProvider, true, None)//Some(s"https://$url")
val s3Client = new S3Client(settings)(system, materializer)

//without
val proxy = Option(Proxy(url, port, "https"))
val settings = new S3Settings(MemoryBufferType, None, awsCredentialsProvider, regionProvider, true, Some($url))
val s3Client = new S3Client(settings)(system, materializer)
```

Thank you for your help.